# Can unbounded sequence minus convergent sequence be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to show an example of the following or prove that it is impossible: an unbounded sequence $(a_n)$ and a convergent sequence $(b_n)$ with $(a_n-b_n)$ bounded.

This is very counterintuitive to me, so I want to prove that it's impossible. All I know so far is that $(a_n-b_n)$ must be divergent (otherwise, the algebraic limit theorem implies that $(a_n)$ must be convergent, but that contradicts its unboundedness).

This is from Abbott's intro analysis text.

Comment: A convergent sequence is bounded, and the sum of two bounded sequences is bounded. Therefore, if $(b_n)$ and $(a_n - b_n)$ are bounded...